# Javascript map function is duplicating values

Tags: javascript, react-native, jsx

I'll be quick, i'm working with react native list item component, which generates lists of items from an array of values, indicating both key and value, onto that, i'm running javascript map, something like this

```
DataManager.ResponseTravelRequestHistory != null ?
  DataManager.ResponseTravelRequestHistory.slice(-3,-1).map((value,index) => (
    <ListItem
      titleStyle={styles.titleListText}
      subtitleStyle={styles.subtitleListText}
      topDivider={true}
      bottomDivider={true}
      key={index.Id}
      leftIcon={<Image resizeMode={"contain"} width={wp("10.8")} source={images.air_transport}/>}
      title={`${TravelsBusiness.FindCityById(value.Ciudad)}`}
      subtitle={`${Moment(value.FechaSalida).format("DD/MM")} al ${Moment(value.FechaRegreso).format("DD/MM")}`}/>
  ))
  :
  null
```

this is filtering the last 3 items (except for the last one), from the array, so the thing is, whenever i request a travel, this whole view should re render and show me the last request i asked, that works, but the problem is, the moment i request a second time, the last one is getting duplicated, so the result is this

[image: Duplicated values]

if i close the app or close session, the data is shown correctly, tried with reverse.slice() but it looks like it works even worse

EDIT: SOLVED! the duplication was made in the datamanager, the reason was that lastobject was part of historyobject list, and everytime i do a new request, the lastobject was duplicated in the historyobject, sort of confusing, but since the main issue wasn't exactly related to listitem, i wanted to share this info, sorry for all the inconvenience

Comment: Are you absolutely positive the duplicate item isn't already in `DataManager.ResponseTravelRequestHistory`? Because `.map()` definitely doesn't duplicate anything.

Comment: it is not, because when i logout from this account, and go back to this screen, everything is normal

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean to use `key={value.Id}` instead of `key={index.Id}`. Because I believe this is causing your problem.

Comment: Sounds right; `index.Id` is undefined, so each ListItem will have the same key (and OP should see a warning about this in the console)

Comment: "Warning: encountered two children with the same key, keys should be unique so that component maintain their identity", i got this warning and also the same duplicate issue

Comment: @NicolasSilva Is there actually an `Id` field on your objects and also be sure that these Id(s) are unique.

Comment: i just discovered one thing, the duplication is occurring in the datamanager itself, this is due to javascript not cleaning the data before insert, which causing me some big issues